# Single post template for specific Custom Post Type using Types plugin Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, types

I'm attempting to setup a custom template for all posts under a specific Custom Post Type, using the Types plugin. I've looked extensively through their documentation and spent a good while attempting to find results on Google but can't find anything.

The recommended single-[name].php setup isn't working/taking effect.

Is there something I'm missing? Some custom code for my functions.php file?

Please advise.

Kind regards,
Patrick

Comment: The `[name]` should be the name of the post type in the backend. This is often NOT the same as the name in the frontend. You're going to need to figure out how the Types plugin prefixes the post type name/slug that it registers.

Comment: On second thought...what is the slug/URL of one of the posts with this custom type?

Comment: Hi Rnevius, the URL structure is; /casestudy/postName. So I need to create a post template for all posts under the 'casestudy' category/post type.

Comment: And you tried making a **single-casestudy.php** template?

Comment: Unfortunately; yes. It didn't appear to take effect however.

Comment: What happened then? If you create a blank template with something like `<?php wp_head(); echo "Test"; wp_footer(); ?>`...what happens?

Comment: Nothing. It just shows/uses the old post template it would appear. Anything I do to single-casestudy.php doesn't appear to make any difference to the post template.

Comment: That being said; it would appear even single.php isn't having an effect either. Could it be using a different template possibly?

Comment: Absolutely. You could try using a plugin such as [Debug Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) to determine which page template is currently in use...

Comment: Great, thanks. It would appear from this query string `casestudy=robstep&post_type=casestudy&name=robstep` that the post_type is indeed casestudy. So surely the single-[postname].php setup should work, no?

Answer (score -1):

single-your_post_type.php should be called, if it is a single post of your_post_type. I suspect that one of the two conditions is not met. Place the following code at top in header.php and check the debug-output.

```
echo is_single() ? 'single' : 'not single';
echo ' : ';
echo get_post_type();
```

It is possible to alter the default template hierarchy with i.e. the 'single_template' hook. Check whether there exists such a filter:

```
echo has_filter( 'single_template' ) ? 'there is one or more single_template filter' : 'no filter exists for single_template';
```

Comment: Hi Tschan,

This returned "Single : casestudy", which corresponds to the setup I have - /casestude/postName/

Comment: I have edited my answer, added the filter hook check.